# Return the first item of a dictionar as a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's assume we have a dictionary like this:

```
>>> d={'a': 4, 'b': 2, 'c': 1.5}
```

If I want to select the first item of `d`, I can simply run the following:

```
>>> first_item = list(d.items())[0]
('a', 4)
```

However, I am trying to have first_item return a dict instead of a tuple i.e., `{'a': 4}`. Thanks for any tips.

Comment: `first_item = dict(list(d.items())[0])`

Comment: Or, too tricky, `first_item = dict(next(iter(d.items())))`.  It does avoid iterating the entire dict.

Comment: Is the order of entries in a dictionary even well-defined?

Comment: In Python 3, yes, it is.  Items come out in the order they were inserted.  That wasn't true in Python 2.

Comment: @TimRoberts: Caveat: 3.6+ (3.7+ explicitly guaranteed).

Comment: If all you ever need is the first item you can use `dict([next(iter(d.items()))])`

Comment: @TimRoberts: Your first two suggestions give the error `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`

Answer (score 2):

Use itertools.islice to avoid creating the entire list, that is unnecessarily wasteful. Here's a helper function:

```
from itertools import islice

def pluck(mapping, pos):
    return dict(islice(mapping.items(), pos, pos + 1))
```

Note, the above will return an empty dictionary if pos is out of bounds, but you can check that inside `pluck` and handle that case however you want (IMO it should probably raise an error).

```
>>> pluck(d, 0)
{'a': 4}
>>> pluck(d, 1)
{'b': 2}
>>> pluck(d, 2)
{'c': 1.5}
>>> pluck(d, 3)
{}
>>> pluck(d, 4)
{}
```

Note, accessing an element by position in a dict requires traversing the dict. If you need to do this more often, for arbitrary positions, consider using a sequence type like `list` which can do it in constant time. Although `dict` objects maintain insertion order, the API doesn't expose any way to manipulate the `dict` as a sequence, so you are stuck with using iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary is a collections of key-value pairs. It is not really ordered collection, though since python 3.7 it keeps the order in which keys were added.

Anyway if you really want some "first" element you can get it in this manner:

```py
some_item = next(iter(d.items()))
```

You should not convert it into a list because it will eat much (O(n)) memory and walk through whole dict as well.

Anyway I'd recommend not to think that dictionary has "first" element. It has keys and values. You can iterate over them in some unknown order (if you do not control how it is created)

Comment: Keeping order in which keys are added means it's ordered.

Comment: It has order internally but you cannot do anything with it execpt iterating